# Python Script to Update MySQL Reporting Too Many Rows Affected

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, query-performance

Good Morning,

I am currently scripting an update to MySQL with Python, which will pull a value from one table and UPDATE another table with said value.  The updates are done in batches, which is configurable, but currently operating at 50K per update. Replication is checked in between each update, with a minor pause (0.01 seconds) induced before each check. 
I am running into the following two issues:

1. The query is acceptably performant initially and for a good chunk of iterations.  As the script runs the time to process each update grows indefinitely until the system seems to stop processing the updates all together.  We started at about 2-3 seconds per update, and it grew to over 4 minutes on the last attempt, roughly after 4-6 hours of iterations.  The MySQL server was still responding, however free buffers were at 1 (unsure if related) and no further updates were processing, although they were recording in the scripts log file.
2. The number of affected rows, gathered via a global variable, is much greater than the actual number of rows that have been updated in the system.  My process is to check the log file for the number of interations, multiply by the 50K, and that should be the rows affected, however, the count is substantially lower.

The script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

# Script Process:
# Py Script to populate all result.orderedPanelOid items from the ordered_panel_result_rel table.
# The UPDATEs are batched in 50K chunks, with replication checks between each batch.
# The largest tenant has about 1.3B result rows and can process a batch in 9-11 seconds.

import mysql.connector,time

#Core Logins
hcmaster_username = 'user_name'
hcmaster_password = 'pw'
hcmaster_hostname = 'host'
hcmaster_database = 'db'

#Tenant Logins
username = 'user_name'
password = 'pw'
hostname_master = 'master_host'
hostname_slave = 'slave_host'

#Define Class
class MySQLCursorDict(mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor):
    def _row_to_python(self, rowdata, desc=None):
        row = super(MySQLCursorDict, self)._row_to_python(rowdata, desc)
        if row:
            return dict(zip(self.column_names, row))
        return None

#Define Record Count
def get_record_count(db_connection, query):
    count_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    count_cursor.execute(query % "SELECT COUNT(*)")
    return count_cursor.fetchall()[0][0]

#Define Check Replication Delay
def check_replication_delay( mysql_connection ):
  id_cursor = mysql_connection.cursor( cursor_class = MySQLCursorDict )
  id_cursor.execute("show slave status")
  try:
      slave_status = id_cursor.fetchall()[0]
      print "%s delay is %d" % ( hostname_slave, int(slave_status['Seconds_Behind_Master']))
      return int(slave_status['Seconds_Behind_Master'])
  except:
      return 0

#Define UPDATE sequence
def update_sequence():

  # Check Replication
  time.sleep(.01)
  while (check_replication_delay(slave) > 30):
      print "Delay is over 30 seconds on RO Slave.  Sleeping for 15 seconds"
      time.sleep(15)

  # Run Query to UPDATE in batches
  #The inner join is req. so that only rows in result with a corresponding rel row are attempted to be updated
  #without the inner join the script loops endlessly because there is no rel value to update result with.
  tenant_cursor.execute(
      "UPDATE %s.result rm inner join (select rm1.id,rm1.OrderedPanelOid,rr1.ResultId,rr1.OrderedPanelId FROM %s.result rm1 inner join %s.ordered_panel_result_rel rr1 on rm1.id = rr1.ResultId WHERE rm1.OrderedPanelOid IS NULL ORDER BY rm1.id LIMIT 50000) as SOURCE ON rm.id = SOURCE.id SET rm.OrderedPanelOid = SOURCE.orderedPanelId WHERE rm.id = SOURCE.ResultId" % (database_encoded, database_encoded, database_encoded))

  # Get affected Rows
  rows_affected = tenant_cursor.rowcount
  global rowsaffected
  rowsaffected = rows_affected
  print rows_affected

  # Commit the UPDATEs
  tenant.commit()

#Collect All Databases
try:
    #Production Core Connection
    db = mysql.connector.connect(user=user_name, password=pw, host=host, database=db, ssl_ca='/file/location')

    #Establish hcmaster Cursor Connections
    hc_cursor = db.cursor()

    #Get Database List -- Change this out when we go full tenant list!
    query = "select databaseName from tenant_environment where databaseName IN ('db1','db2');"
    hc_cursor.execute(query)
    databases = hc_cursor.fetchall()
    tenant_list = list(zip(*databases)[0])
    tenant_listStr = str(tenant_list)

    print "Databases to execute upon: " + tenant_listStr

except Exception as err:
        e = str(err)
        print "Something has gone wrong in collecting databases! " + e

for database in databases:
    databaseStr = str(database)
    database_encoded = databaseStr.strip()[3:-3]
    print "Trying " + database_encoded

    # Production Connections
    tenant = mysql.connector.connect(user=user_name, password=pw, host=master_host, database=database_encoded,ssl_ca='/file/location')
    slave = mysql.connector.connect(user=user_name, password=pw, host=slave_host, database=database_encoded,ssl_ca='/file/location')

    # Establish Cursor Connections
    tenant_cursor = tenant.cursor()

    # Collect Start Time
    print database_encoded + " start time: " + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    try:
        update_sequence()
        while rowsaffected > 0:
            print "Number of Rows Affected: " + str(rowsaffected) + " at " + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            update_sequence()
        else:
            print "Number of Rows Affected: 0"

    except Exception as err:
        e = str(err)
        print database_encoded + ".result.orderedPanelOid was not populated! Process failed! " + e

    #Collect End Time
    print database_encoded + " completion time: " + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "\n"
```

I would appreciate any help or ideas as I am a bit stumped on both issues.  I am a newer DBA but have written a few python scripts up until now.  MySQL version is 5.6.34, using python 2.7

---

The query, formatted for readability:

```
 UPDATE %s.result rm
 inner join (select rm1.id,rm1.OrderedPanelOid,
                    rr1.ResultId,rr1.OrderedPanelId 
               FROM %s.result rm1 
              inner join %s.ordered_panel_result_rel rr1 on rm1.id = rr1.ResultId 
              WHERE rm1.OrderedPanelOid IS NULL 
              ORDER BY rm1.id 
              LIMIT 50000
            ) as SOURCE ON rm.id = SOURCE.id 
   SET rm.OrderedPanelOid = SOURCE.orderedPanelId 
 WHERE rm.id = SOURCE.ResultId
```

Create Table statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `result` (
  `id` decimal(30,0) NOT NULL,
  `v` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createStamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `modifiedStamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdBy` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modifiedBy` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `testData` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `testOid` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orderedPanelOid` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `result` longtext,
  `numericResult` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` longtext,
  `description` longtext,
  `status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `units` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `refRange` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `refRangeLowNumeric` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `refRangeHighNumeric` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `patientOid` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `labOrderOid` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `placeOrderNumber` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `criticality` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conclusionTypeValueId` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `runDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `resultDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `enteredByOid` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `signedByOid` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_modified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `resultLocalDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `runLocalDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_resultDate` (`resultDate`),
  KEY `idx_runDate` (`runDate`),
  KEY `idx_name` (`name`),
  KEY `idx_code` (`code`),
  KEY `idx_patientOid` (`patientOid`),
  KEY `idx_labOrderOid` (`labOrderOid`),
  KEY `idx_placeOrderNumber` (`placeOrderNumber`),
  KEY `idx_orderedPanelOid` (`orderedPanelOid`),
  KEY `idx_enteredByOid` (`enteredByOid`),
  KEY `idx_testOid` (`testOid`),
  KEY `idx_active` (`active`),
  KEY `idx_signedByOid` (`signedByOid`),
  KEY `idx_row_modified_at` (`row_modified_at`),
  KEY `idx_resultLocalDate` (`resultLocalDate`),
  KEY `idx_runLocalDate` (`runLocalDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

    CREATE TABLE `ordered_panel_result_rel` (
  `id` decimal(30,0) NOT NULL,
  `orderedPanelId` decimal(30,0) NOT NULL,
  `resultId` decimal(30,0) NOT NULL,
  `row_modified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_uqopResultIds` (`orderedPanelId`,`resultId`),
  KEY `SET` (`orderedPanelId`,`resultId`),
  KEY `OPANELRESRELID` (`orderedPanelId`),
  KEY `idx_orderedPanelId` (`orderedPanelId`),
  KEY `idx_resultId` (`resultId`),
  KEY `idx_row_modified_at` (`row_modified_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  Please pay special attention to the section on query performance. Please [edit] your question to provide more details, especially about your indexes.

Comment: Why do you think the affected rows per iteration is 50k? And can you provide the create table statements for the tables?

Comment: Sorry about that--I was testing on 10000 and forgot to update before pasting here.  Fixing that now

Comment: o. Jones, Create table statements have been added.  I will check the link, thank you

Comment: I should probably clarify that I don't think this is a question of the query and it's performance.  I can run the UPDATE singularly, as well as for about 4 hours of iterations before the process begins to slow and mysql seems to be halting the updates.  I am not certain but I think it might be attempting to clear cache or perhaps the buffers are full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for 50K rows that need fixing.  But after you have fixed a batch, the next batch is farther into the table?  That will only get slower and slower.

The workaround is to walk through the table based on the `PRIMARY KEY` instead.  Get clumps of 50K rows, fix however many need fixing in that 50K (which might be less than 50K).  This will change from "slower and slower" to a constant, fast, speed per chunk.

I discuss details of such chunking here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Other issues...

- 50K is probably too much in a single chunk, especially with Replication in use.
- Why `DECIMAL(30,0)`?  It is bulky (14 bytes) and is probably a lot bigger than necessary.  See `INT` and its friends.
- Do you have multiple 'identical' `DATABASEs`?  Unless you are hosting some kind of service, that is usually a poor schema design.
- Single-column index on a flag (such as on `active`) is rarely useful.
- A `PRIMARY KEY` is, by definition (in MySQL), `UNIQUE`; don't re-index.
- If `ordered_panel_result_rel` is a many:many relationship table, see the tips in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table
- Both the tables with schema have an `PRIMARY KEY(id)` that is not `AUTO_INCREMENT`; are you setting the value manually?

Comment: Thank you, Rick--this is very helpful.  Oddly enough I have used that exact page before in generalized MySQL but have never tried to pair it with python.  I need to python to be the looping engine as I check replication between each iteration or batched update.  
I am a bit perplexed at first glance on how to gather the ID's via python, then trigger the update using said range, without really slowing things down though--If you have any ideas I will gladly take them.  Thanks again.

Comment: First, use a `SELECT` to get a max_id for a range.  Then use `UPDATE` with a `WHERE id BETWEEN ...`.  No `JOIN`, no list of ids, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Rick.  I was able to figure out a solution late last night where I get the min, store as a variable, same for max, then use the update on those...it works perfectly!  You unknowingly saved me with a past stored procedure and again here--thank you!  I will add a follow up with the updated script once it is completely baked out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated script.  Thanks again, @Rick James for the push in the right direction.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

# Script Process:
# Py Script to populate all result.orderedPanelOid items from the ordered_panel_result_rel table.
# The UPDATEs are batched in 10K chunks, with replication checks between each batch.


import mysql.connector,time

#Core Logins
hcmaster_username = 'username'
hcmaster_password = 'pw'
hcmaster_hostname = 'host'
hcmaster_database = 'db'

#Tenant Logins
username = 'username'
password = 'pw'
hostname_master = 'masterhost'
hostname_slave = 'slavehost'

#Define Class
class MySQLCursorDict(mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor):
    def _row_to_python(self, rowdata, desc=None):
        row = super(MySQLCursorDict, self)._row_to_python(rowdata, desc)
        if row:
            return dict(zip(self.column_names, row))
        return None

#Define Record Count
def get_record_count(db_connection, query):
    count_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    count_cursor.execute(query % "SELECT COUNT(*)")
    return count_cursor.fetchall()[0][0]

#Define Check Replication Delay
def check_replication_delay( mysql_connection ):
  id_cursor = mysql_connection.cursor( cursor_class = MySQLCursorDict )
  id_cursor.execute("show slave status")
  try:
      slave_status = id_cursor.fetchall()[0]
      print "%s delay is %d" % ( hostname_slave, int(slave_status['Seconds_Behind_Master']))
      return int(slave_status['Seconds_Behind_Master'])
  except:
      return 0

#Define UPDATE sequence
def update_sequence():

  # Check Replication
  time.sleep(.01)
  while (check_replication_delay(slave) > 30):
      print "Delay is over 30 seconds on RO Slave.  Sleeping for 15 seconds"
      time.sleep(15)

  # Begin the Batch Updates with Bracketed Ranges

  #find minimum id from set
  tenant_cursor.execute("SELECT rm.id from %s.result rm inner join %s.ordered_panel_result_rel rr on rm.id = rr.ResultId WHERE rm.id = rr.ResultId AND rm.orderedPanelOid is NULL ORDER BY rm.id ASC LIMIT 1" % (database_encoded, database_encoded))
  min = tenant_cursor.fetchone()
  print min

  #Deal with 0 rows
  if min is None:
    rows_affected = -1
    global rowsaffected
    rowsaffected = rows_affected
    pass

  else:
    # find maximum id from range
    smin = str(min[0])
    tenant_cursor.execute("SELECT rm.id from %s.result rm inner join %s.ordered_panel_result_rel rr on rm.id = rr.ResultId WHERE rm.id = rr.ResultId AND rm.orderedPanelOid is NULL AND rm.id >= %s ORDER BY rm.id ASC LIMIT 10000,1" % (database_encoded, database_encoded, smin))
    max = tenant_cursor.fetchone()
    print max

    # Execute on Last Batch of ID's
    if max is None or min[0] >= max[0]:
      smin = str(min[0])
      tenant_cursor.execute("UPDATE %s.result rm inner join %s.ordered_panel_result_rel rr on rm.id = rr.ResultId SET rm.OrderedPanelOid = rr.orderedPanelId WHERE rm.id = rr.ResultId AND rm.OrderedPanelOid IS NULL and rm.id >= %s" % (database_encoded, database_encoded, smin))

      # Get affected Rows
      rows_affected = tenant_cursor.rowcount
      global rowsaffected
      rowsaffected = rows_affected
      print rows_affected

    #Or Execute on All Other Batches of ID's
    else:
      smin = str(min[0])
      smax = str(max[0])
      tenant_cursor.execute("UPDATE %s.result rm inner join %s.ordered_panel_result_rel rr on rm.id = rr.ResultId SET rm.OrderedPanelOid = rr.orderedPanelId WHERE rm.id = rr.ResultId AND rm.OrderedPanelOid IS NULL and rm.id >= %s AND rm.id < %s" % (database_encoded, database_encoded, smin, smax))

      # Get affected Rows
      rows_affected = tenant_cursor.rowcount
      global rowsaffected
      rowsaffected = rows_affected
      print rows_affected

    # Commit the UPDATEs
    tenant.commit()

#Collect All Databases
try:
    #Production Core Connection
    master = mysql.connector.connect(user=master_username, password=master_password, host=master_hostname, database=master_database, ssl_ca='/file/location')

    #Establish master Cursor Connections
    cursor = master.cursor()

    #Get Database List -- Change this out when we go full tenant list!
    query = "select databaseName from master.tenant_environment where databaseName IN ('db1','db2');"
    hc_cursor.execute(query)
    databases = hc_cursor.fetchall()
    tenant_list = list(zip(*databases)[0])
    tenant_listStr = str(tenant_list)

    print "Databases to execute upon: " + tenant_listStr

except Exception as err:
        e = str(err)
        print "Something has gone wrong in collecting databases! " + e

for database in databases:
    databaseStr = str(database)
    database_encoded = databaseStr.strip()[3:-3]
    print "Trying " + database_encoded

    # Production Connections
    tenant = mysql.connector.connect(user=username, password=password, host=hostname_master, database=database_encoded,ssl_ca='/file/location')
    slave = mysql.connector.connect(user=username, password=password, host=hostname_slave, database=database_encoded,ssl_ca='/file/location')

    # Establish Cursor Connections
    tenant_cursor = tenant.cursor()

    # Collect Start Time
    print database_encoded + " start time: " + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    try:
        update_sequence()
        while rowsaffected > 0:
            print "Number of Rows Affected: " + str(rowsaffected) + " at " + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            update_sequence()
        else:
            print "Number of Rows Affected: 0"

    except Exception as err:
        e = str(err)
        print database_encoded + ".result.orderedPanelOid was not populated! Process failed! " + e

    #Collect End Time
    print database_encoded + " completion time: " + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "\n"
```